# Observable collection changes are not reflected on Maps Control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, mvvmcross

I am creating an app where I am using MvvmCross on WP7 along with a Bing Maps control. I am trying to bind the `MapItemsControl` `ItemSource` to an `ObservableCollection` of `LocationDataSource`, which contain a property `MapPosition` of the type `GeoPoint`. `GeoPoint` is a simple class which contain information about the Latitude and Longitude of the location.
The locations which I populate into the `ObservableCollection` are fetched by a service which my `ViewModel` listens to and updates the collection when it has fetched the locations. Though it does not seem to work as no locations are shown on the map.
To bind the `GeoPoint`s I have made a converter which simply converts to `GeoCoordinate` which the `MapItemsControl` understands. I know the converter works as I am using it to bind to the `Map` `Center` property.

The binding looks like this:

```
<maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
    <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding MapPosition, Converter={StaticResource GeoPoint}}" Template="{StaticResource pinSiteLoc}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</maps:MapItemsControl>
```

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<LocationDataModel> _locations;
public ObservableCollection<LocationDataModel> Locations
{
    get { return _locations; } 
    set
    {
        _locations = value;
        FirePropertyChanged(() => Locations);
    }
}
```

I have tried various ways to update the `Locations` collection, which is done in the `ViewModel` in an event handler after the `ViewModel` has loaded and is ready, I assumed this would be working:

```
Locations = LocationDataService.Locations;
```

I have checked that `LocationDataService.Locations` is not empty and contains an actual location.
I also tried intantiating the collection the the `ViewModel` constructor and then `add` each element to the collection, which did not show anything on the map either.

**EDIT**
As per request in the comments. I have tried adding the locations like this to the collection, where it was instantiated as `Locations = new ObservableCollection<LocationDataModel>();` in the `ViewModel` constructor. Then in the event handler it was populated as such:

```
private void LocationDataServiceOnLoadingChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (LocationDataService.IsInventoryLoaded)
    {
        foreach (var location in LocationDataService.Locations)
        {
            Locations.Add(location);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the code where you're adding the items?

Comment: @Steve Danner: I added to the question.

Comment: Is your `GeoPoint` converter getting called? i.e. is the problem before, during or after it?

Comment: The converter gets called once with the values 0;0 although the location coordinates are 55;12, but this is correct, as it is called before the collection is populated. After it gets populated the converter is not called. It works for my Map.Center binding where it gets called quite a lot with the correct values.

Comment: Sounds very odd - I'm sure I've seen this working in wp7 projects! I can't see anything you are doing wrong. Does it work in a plain single file project - no mvvm, just handcrafted Page with a DataContext?

Comment: This works in an old app where I also use Mvvm, though not MvvmCross, I am in the process of branching this out as it is too tightly integrated with code for a web client. So I am reusing a lot of that old code on top of MvvmCross along with its services to load data instead of the data loading directly in the ViewModels like it is done in the old app. The code for the map binding is identical except for the `GeoPoint` converter. It would be a lot of work to test this in a new single file project as the startup of the app is complex.

Comment: OK. I just thought maybe test a converter, a collection and a map - not everything else. Because this is a Map binding direct to an ObservableCollection I can only really guess this is a conversion issue somehow... but overall it just doesn't make sense to me. Q "Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?" A No!

Comment: I found the error. It was not related to Mvvm or the converter. I closed the `Map` control prematurely and it did not surround the `MapItemsControl`. Sorry for wasting you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment I made to the question, I found an error in the xaml file, where I prematurely closed the `Map` control tag like so:

```
<maps:Map
    (..)
    />
<maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
    <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding MapPosition, Converter={StaticResource GeoPoint}}" Template="{StaticResource pinSiteLoc}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</maps:MapItemsControl>
```

Instead it had to be:

```
<maps:Map
    (..)
    >
    <maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding MapPosition, Converter={StaticResource GeoPoint}}" Template="{StaticResource pinSiteLoc}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
</maps:Map>
```